# Is it possible not to pass some form fields in GET request?

Tags: jquery, forms, input, submit

I have a form with some input texts passed in GET, and i don't want to have in GET all the fields; i want to avoid empty fields.

So, a concrete example for:

```
<form method="GET" action="an_url">
    <input type="text" name="field1"/>
    <input type="text" name="field2"/>
    <input type="text" name="field3"/>
    <input type="submit" value="submit"/>
</form>
```

I supposed that fields disabled by html attribute "disabled" shouldn't be passed to GET.

So i have done a js (based on jquery) to disable empty fields on submit, something like this:

```
$("form").submit(function() {
    $(this).find("input[type=text]").each( function () {
        if (!$.trim($(this).val())) {
            $(this).attr("disabled", "true");
        }
    });
});
```

However, this doesn't work. Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can remove the `name` attribute like this:

```
 $("form").submit(function() {
     $(this).find("input[type=text]").each( function () {

        if (!$.trim($(this).val())) {
            $(this).removeAttr("name");
        }
     });
 });
```

From the [W3C Recommendation](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/interact/forms.html):

> When a form is submitted for processing, some controls have their name paired with their current value and these pairs are submitted with the form. Those controls for which name/value pairs are submitted are called successful controls.

Answer (score 3):

The `disabled` attribute accepts one, and only one value: `disabled`. Setting it to `true` is not allowed.

(Setting the `disabled` **property** is a different story, it is either `true` or `false`)